# EDW index question

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index-tuning, data-warehouse, sql-server-2017

I have been assigned the task of designing a dimension or fact table for an EDW.

I know that a SQL Server table supports only one rowstore clustered index (conventional clustered index) and that you can create as many rowstore nonclustered indexes (conventional non-clusterd indexes) as required.

I would like to know if clustered columnstore and nonclustered indexes can be added to the same SQL Server table.

For instance, can I create a table with **one rowstore clustered index** (clusterd index), **two nonclustered rowstore indexes** (non-clustered indexes), **and one nonclustered columnstore index**?

Versions of the SQL Server database engine where we store our data: 2014, 2016, and 2017.

Comment: Is it correct that you wrote _I'm concerned with dimension or fact table design for EDW_ but that you possibly meant _I have been assigned the task of designing a dimenstion or fact table for an EDW_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can [easily be done](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=188a0936fa60d0058d18cd022f177b45) in SQL Server 2016. You can create nonclustered rowstore indexes and one nonclustered columnstore index on a table even if that table already has a clustered rowstore index.

This can also be done in SQL Server 2014, but [data cannot be modified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589806(v=sql.120).aspx) in the table after the NCCI is created.

I suggest reading the documentation and trying things out in SSMS.